# How to log User Agent and Referer to Serilog?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I want to log the UserAgent and Referer in a .Net Core web application.  I don't see anything obvious in the Serilog [documentation](https://serilog.net/).  Nor do I see it in any of the official [enrichers](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment).

So is there something simple I am overlooking?

I am aware that I can use middleware to add items to the LogContext via `LogContext.PushProperty`, but I'd rather not waste cycles if Serilog already has the capability.

Comment: Have a look at this [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.AspnetcoreHttpcontext/) from [GitHub](https://github.com/trenoncourt/serilog-enrichers-aspnetcore-httpcontext)

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the User-Agent value from the Request object and push it into the LogContext.
Here is a sample code..

```
app.Use(async (httpContext, next) =>
        {                
            LogContext.PushProperty("User-Agent", httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"]);
            await next.Invoke();
        }
);
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid PushProperty if possible.